# Display freezes within 10 seconds after log in (Intel graphic card)

Tags: drivers, graphics, hp, intel

I am having some trouble solved this one even after consulting similar problems in the forum and would appreciate any help and guidance. I don't know what started the problem (maybe an update or maybe the heat wave)
Here is my system configuration running on recovery mode :

```
lsb_release -a
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal

lspci | grep VGA
VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07)

lshw -C Display
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: UHD Graphics 620
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 07
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:a0000000-a0ffffff memory:90000000-9fffffff ioport:3000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Comment: "display UNCLAIMED" is certainly a problem.

Comment: I'm running the OS on recovery mode. I cant use it otherwise

Comment: Maybe time for a complete purge and re install?